# Covariance Matrix with missing data

Tags: variance, covariance, covariance-matrix

I want to calculate a Variance Covariance matrix for a set of stock.

Suppose I have 3 stock, 
Stock 1 listed in 2001 
Stock 2 listed in 2008
Stock 3 listed in 2011

I will then have missing data beteewn stock listing dates

Would I be correct to calculate the variance using the whole data set for stock 1 and the covariance between the stock 1 and stock 2 using data starting from 2008? or should I use for both variance and covariance the same time frame not counting for dates prior to 2008 for the variance of stock 1?

Comment: Hi: google fo the name stambaugh. he wrote a seminal paper years ago on dealing with mis-aligned data when building covariance matrices. If you can't find it, let me know and I'll try to find it.

Comment: thanks, will take a look